# Establecer el penultimo bit a uno

Tags: python, operador, numero

tenia un reto con mi hermano para intentar establecer el penultimo bit de un numero a uno, por ejemplo si el numero era `0b100` deberia quedar en `0b110` o si era `0b1000` deberia quedar `0b1100`. Logre hacerlo de la siguente forma en python:

```py
def setp(n):
  if n == 0: return 1
  if n == 1: return 1
  count = 0

  while n >> count != 1:
   count += 1

  return n | (2 ** (count - 1))
```

Pero mi duda es, hay una mas optima de hacerlo?, sin usar un bucle while?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Si a un bit le haces un OR (símbolo "|" pipe) con el bit 1, siempre obtienes 1. Es decir: 0|1=1, 1|1=1. Por lo que si quieres que el segundo bit empezando por la derecha sea siempre uno, lo único que tienes que hacer es hacerle OR con el número 10 en binario (o 2 en decimal): `return n|2`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se puede resolver con complejidad O(1) en lugar de O(n) como planteas en tu solución (es decir que se puede hacer sin tener que usar un bucle).

Para ello hay que recordar las propiedades de la operaciones binarias, en particular la de la operación OR.

Recordemos la tabla de verdad de la operación OR:

```
 A | B | A OR B
---+---+-------
 0 | 0 |   0
 0 | 1 |   1
 1 | 0 |   1
 1 | 1 |   1
```

- **Fíjate que cuando A es 1, el resultado siempre es 1.**
- **Fíjate que cuando A es 0, el resultado siempre es lo mismo que B.**

Ahora lo que quieres es transformar solo uno de los bits y ponerlo a 1, dejando los demás tal y como estaban.

Partes de este número de ejemplo:

```
100
```

y lo quieres convertir en

```
110
```

es decir, fijar el segundo bit a 1 y dejar los demás como estaban.

Por lo que hemos visto antes, si haces OR 1 con un bit, lo conviertes en 1 sea lo que sea, y si haces OR 0 con un bit, dejas el bit sin alterar. Por lo que vamos a hacer OR de esta manera:

```
    100
OR  010
-------
    110
```

Esto es tu número de entrada OR 010. Fíjate si vamos bit por bit de izquerda a derecha que:

- 1 OR 0 es 1, el tercer bit empezando por la derecha queda sin alterar.
- 0 OR 1 es 1, el segundo bit empezando por la derecha queda modificado.
- 0 OR 0 es 0, el primer bit empezando por la derecha queda sin alterar.

Si el número de entrada fuese más largo, lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir ceros por la izquierda, pero como sabemos, añadir ceros por la izquierda no cambia el número.

Es decir: 10, 010, 0010, 00010, etc. es el mismo número, y ese número en decimal es el número 2.

Por lo que lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer OR 2 con tu número de entrada.

En python:

```
def setp(n):
  return n | 2
```

Ya que estás haciendo retos: ¿Qué pasaría si quisieras convertirlo a 1 en vez de a 0? ¿Y si el número de entrada tiene más de 3 bits? Échale un vistazo a la operación AND y a ver qué se te ocurre.

Más info:

- Operaciones binarias: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/booleanos-operaciones-logicas-y-binarias/
- Máscaras de bits: https://peon-pasado.github.io/competitive-programming-classes/web/class-14.html
- Complejidad algorítmica y notación Big-O: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Rendimiento-de-algoritmos-y-notacion-Big-O.aspx

Feliz año

Comment: Según entiendo, se refiere al penúltimo bit, de derecha a izquierda.

Comment: @Mateo , es correcto, el penúltimo de derecha a izquierda

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué sería lo óptimo? ¿Menor uso memoria? ¿Menor tiempo de ejecución? ¿Menor cantidad de líneas de código?.

Si te refieres a menor tiempo de ejecución, yo creo que tu código está bastante bien. Aunque cambiaría la última línea por esta:

```
return n | 1 << (count - 1)
```

En decimal desplazar dígitos equivale a multiplicar o dividir por 10. Desplazar bits equivale a multiplicar o dividir por 2 y es más rápido.

Si necesitas que sea más rápido considera usar un lenguaje de menor nivel, como C, Rust, Zig o incluso ensamblador.

---

Si te refieres a menor cantidad de código, te propongo el siguiente:

```
def setp(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n

    return n | 1 << len(bin(n)) - 4
```

Es bastante compacto aunque probablemente pierda tiempo y memoria convirtiendo el número a `bin`, y luego obteniendo su longitud.

Para conocer la cantidad de bits, seguramente sea mejor utilizar [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=log2#math.log2):

```
# Con el logaritmo obtienes el exponente al que tienes que elevar 2 para obtener n.
# Si tomas la parte entera obtienes el exponente del cuadrado perfecto más cercano.
return n | 1 << int(math.log2(n)) - 1
```

O [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```
return n | 1 << n.bit_length() - 2
```

Comment: Muy interesante :).